# Remove all capital letters from a particular column in a CSV file

Tags: text-processing, csv

I am having a CSV file containing 3000+ lines in the following format:

```
R1C1, ABC123abc, R1C3
R2C1, DEFG456defg, R2C3
R3C1, HIJKL789hijkl, R3C3
```

I need to remove all the capital letters from the second column of the file so that it reads as follows:

```
R1C1, 123abc, R1C3
R2C1, 456defg, R2C3
R3C1, 789hijkl, R3C3
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
$ awk -F',' '{sub(/[[:upper:]]+/,"",$2)}1' OFS=',' file
R1C1, 123abc, R1C3
R2C1, 456defg, R2C3
R3C1, 789hijkl, R3C3
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I want to remove string before first alphabet in small caps? For example: `R1C1, abc, R1C3` in this case.

Comment: In this case, it can be `sub(/[[:upper:]]+[[:digit:]]+/,"",$2)`.

Comment: In case, if I need to mention multiple strings in the regex part, like `ABC,DEFG,HIJKL`, then how can I do that?

Comment: `[[:upper:]]+` matches all of them. If you want string literal, `ABC|DEFG|HIJK`.

Answer (score 2):

if the second field has capitals scattered,

```
awk -F ',' '{gsub(/[[:upper:]]/, X, $2)}1' OFS=, file
```

Answer (score 1):

With [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`):

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N put '$2 = gsub($2, "[[:upper:]]", "")' file
R1C1, 123abc, R1C3
R2C1, 456defg, R2C3
R3C1, 789hijkl, R3C3
```

This reads the data as a header-less CSV file and modifies the 2nd field of each record by substituting all upper-case letters with nothing (i.e., removing them).

Answer (score -2):

Bash in combination with `sed`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cnt=0;
while IFS=, read a b c; 
do 
 echo -n $a ; cnt=$[cnt+1]; 
 sed  -e 's/[^,]*,\([^,]*\).*/\1/' file | 
 sed  -e 's/\([[:upper:]]\)//g'| 
 sed  -e  $cnt'q;d'|
 tr '\n' ' ' ;
 echo  $c; 
done  < file
```

produces:

```
R1C1 123abc R1C3
R2C1 456defg R2C3
R3C1 789hijkl R3C3
```

Comment: Downvoter comment?

Comment: You seem to have lost the field delimiters in your final output.